# Android SDK Not Installing Packages

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I am having trouble using the android SDK, and I am running it 'As Administrator' when I start it up.

Here is a good example, just now I selected the item

'EDK 1.2 by Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB'

It says it was installing, and at the end I have it in my list twice like this,

```
EDK 1.2 by Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 10 1     Not Installed
EDK 1.2 by Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 10 1     Installed
```

It seems to be confused. In this case when I refreshed the list it said that the item was installed, but I am having a lot of cases where it just refuses to install the item.

I also had a case where in the list it said an item was installed, but when I came back later it wasn't installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "name doesn't match" issue which also happens when you download other add-ons like addon-dual_screen_apis-kyocera_corporation, addon-galaxy_tab-samsung_electronics and 
addon-real3d-lge, you can fix it by the following steps:

Step 0: if you've downloaded more than one copy of the same add-on then keep only one and remove all the others.

```
Android SDK:\add-ons\addon-edk_1_2-sony_ericsson_mobile_communications_ab-10
Android SDK:\add-ons\addon-edk_1_2-sony_ericsson_mobile_communications_ab-10-1 (remove it)
```

Step 1. Find out the real add-on name and the vendor name

Open the add-on's source.properties as a text file and you can find the url to the repository

Android SDK:\add-ons\addon-edk_1_2-sony_ericsson_mobile_communications_ab-10\source.properties

```
...
Pkg.SourceUrl=http\://developer.sonyericsson.com/edk/android/repository.xml
...
```

then browse the url:

http://developer.sonyericsson.com/edk/android/repository.xml

```
...
<sdk:name>EDK 1.2</sdk:name>
...
<sdk:vendor>Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB</sdk:vendor>
...
```

Step 2. Edit the manifest of the add-on to match the names found in step 1.

Android SDK:\add-ons\addon-edk_1_2-sony_ericsson_mobile_communications_ab-10\manifest.ini

```
name=EDK 1.2
vendor=Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB
```

Then restart the SDK Manager you will see that the SDK is marked as "Installed"

Regards

Ziteng Chen