# Android SDK installation failed - Connection reset. Nothing is installed

Tags: android, sdk, installation

Hello I have a problem with installing the packages using the Android SDK Manager.

I get Connection reset.  Nothing is installed.

I am on Windows 7 64 bits using JDK 7.

Here is what I tried so far without success:

Installed Android SDK installer_r18-windows.exe

Then run Android SDK Manager as Administrator and I can select which packages I want to install.

So far so good.

Then when I select the packages I want and click Install then the log says:

Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
peer not authenticated

I googled this error and they say that you need to set Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://....

If I do that and click install I get this error:

Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
Connection reset

At every package it tries to install.

I tried setting the proxy setting according to my internet providers setting. I get the errors again.

I tried deactivating the firewall. Same errors.

So how do I get the Andoid SDK Manager to install the packages succesfully?.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Trying again later might work, or if the machine is a laptop go someplace else and try.  Something that often works is to google the unofficial instructions for doing an "offline" sdk install by extracting the download paths from the xml file - this is especially useful if you find you need to use a machine in a different location to obtain the downloads and bring them on a usb stick to the machine you are trying to install on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It solved my problem. I found
the APD - Offline Android SDK Package Installer solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help. I cannot seem to mark an comment as an answer. Too bad cause you had the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Others have also faced similar problems when downloadind SDK components.

A simple way to fix this problem is to modify the *Pkg.SourceUrl* property, changing HTTPS to HTTP to avoid secure downloads, as illustrated in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936461/android-sdk-not-installing-packages).

Comment: Thank you. I searched for source.properties on my harddisk but it did not contain Pkg.SourceUrl=. It contains this:

Pkg.UserSrc=false
Pkg.Revision=18
Platform.MinPlatformToolsRev=11

Also the Android SDK -> platforms directory does not contain any  files. So I cannot find the Pkg.SourceUrl in any text file anywhere.

What to do?

Comment: On my PC, this is the location of the file you need to modify: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\source.properties. You were looking at C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\source.properties.

Comment: No, I did not have a  C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\source.properties file or directory. It simply was not there. Anyway the APD -  Offline Android SDK Package Installer solved the problem. I do have a C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\source.properties NOW (After the APD installation) but still it does not contain Pkg.SourceUrl. Still thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. In my case, the download would start and then abort with the same error message.

If the download starts and then aborts, try downloading again - SDK Manager will resume the download where it aborted. It doesn't advertise that feature (let alone resume by itself), but the log entries report that it is in fact resuming the download.

You might need to retry a few times - depending on how stable your Internet connection is and how much you download. Not too elegant, but will do for a quick on-the-fly install.

Answer (score 0):

This may be cause of system time may have changed. Synchronize your system time with one of the internet time servers. Restart the installation. Hope it works.